# x-, y-positions of viewport's right, bottom edges (respectively)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm looking for a *plugin-free* way to get the x-coordinate of the visible viewport's right edge, and likewise, the y-coordinate of its bottom edge, using either jQuery or "plain" JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: "plugin-free" and "using jQuery" don't belong in the same sentence...

Comment: I would disagree. 
jQuery is a library. You extend it's functionality with "plugins"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally settled for this (jQuery-based) solution:

```
var $w = $(window);
var right_edge_x  = $w.scrollLeft() + $w.width();
var bottom_edge_y = $w.scrollTop()  + $w.height();
```

I'm not sure exactly how it differs from the other solutions proposed, let alone whether it's better, but at least I can make some sense of it...

Answer (score 6):

```
var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth;
var height= document.documentElement.clientHeight|| window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get you: I did not ask for *dimensions* (widths or heights), I asked for *positions* (the coordinates of the viewport's lower right corner).  If the user scrolls the page, this position *will* change, but the dimensions won't.

Comment: In that case, you can just add the scroll position.

Comment: Well, that's part of what I'm asking how to do.

Comment: Take what I gave above, and add `document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop`. For the width, do the same with `Left`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the window object. It would be something along the lines of

```
winX = window.screenX + window.outerWidth;

winY = window.screenY + window.outerHeight;
```

Anyways, I think you get the idea. The good news is that it is pure vanilla JS.

The full docs can be found here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
  const { scrollY, innerHeight, scrollX, innerWidth } = window
  const viewport = {
    top: scrollY,
    bottom: scrollY + innerHeight,
    left: scrollX,
    right: scrollX + innerWidth,
  }
```